# Yii2. Apply Custom URL rule class

Tags: php, url, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have created a custom URL rule and want to put some logic there, but `parseRequest` and `createUrl` methods are not executing.

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Object;
use yii\web\UrlRuleInterface;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
class CustomUrlRule extends Object implements UrlRuleInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
        die();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws \yii\base\InvalidConfigException
     */
    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
        die();
    }
}
```

And then write it in `UrlManager` `$rules`

```
    'enablePrettyUrl'     => true,
    'showScriptName'      => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules'               => [
        'class'   => 'app\components\CustomUrlRule',
    //other rules...
```

]

But the code is not executing. I can still a page of my app. How to apply my useless `CustomUrlRule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper UrlManager example configuration is:

```
'rules' => [
    ['class' => 'MyUrlRule', 'pattern' => '...', 'route' => 'site/index', ...],
    // ...
]
```

You need to wrap this in another array.

Edit: You don't have to extend `yii\web\UrlRule` instead of `yii\base\Object` as I posted before, just proper interface is required.

Comment: Could it be an error in [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-rules)?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, just interface is required.

Comment: Thank you. In 4 minutes I will accept the answer :)