# How to implement the patterns array in the urlManager of web.php?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-urlmanager

I have a Yii2 app. And I try to add the patterns array in the urlManager of web.php. And I serached a lot and fount a lot of links with the correct soltuion. For example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873686/yii2-apply-custom-url-rule-class
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing
```

But It didn't resolved the issue.

So if I do it like:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            
            'rules' =>  [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/user', 
                'POST' => 'v1/user/signup',
                'POST' => 'v1/user/login',
                
                
            ],                          
            
        ],
```

And in postman I do a post on this url: `http://localhost:8080/v1/user/login`

everything works fine. But if I do this:

```
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            
            'rules' =>  [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/user', 
                'patterns' => [
                    'POST' => 'signup',
                    'POST login' => 'login',
                    'OPTIONS login' => 'options',                    
                ],
                
                
            ],                         
            
        ],
```

the whole web.php file looks:

```
<?php
// phpcs:ignoreFile

$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'name' => 'internetsuite 2.0',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\v1\Module',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [

            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'OEtCunrAfQNETtmUSDnZw1JPHTB44i3A',
        ],
        

        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => \yii\symfonymailer\Mailer::class,
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            
            'rules' =>  [[
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/user', 
                'pluralize' => false,
                ],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'OPTIONS {login}' => 'options',                    
                    'POST signup' => 'signup',
                    'POST login' => 'login',
                ],
                
                
            ],                         
            
        ],

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlRule::POST
```

And I need the OPTIONS parameter because I call an api call from an react app.

Question: how to implement the pattern in the urlManager correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem in your whole `web.php` config code.
You put `'extraPatterns'` outside the rest rule configuration so it's treated as another rule instead of part of rest rule.

```php
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            
            'rules' =>  [[
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/user', 
                'pluralize' => false,
                ], // <-- THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'OPTIONS {login}' => 'options',                    
                    'POST signup' => 'signup',
                    'POST login' => 'login',
                ],
                // Here should end the yii\rest\UrlRule configuration
                
            ],                         
            
        ],
```

So correct configuration should look like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
            'controller' => 'v1/user', 
            'pluralize' => false,
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'OPTIONS {login}' => 'options',                    
                'POST signup' => 'signup',
                'POST login' => 'login',
            ],
        ],    
    ],
],
```

Side note: I don't know why you put `login` inside of braces like this `{login}` but it doesn't feel right. `OPTIONS login` would match OPTIONS request send to route like this `v1/user/login`. When you put it inside braces you are telling `UrlRule` to replace it with token defined in [`$tokens`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$tokens-detail) array.

Comment: #Michal HynčicaOke, so it is login without {}? But you have given the solution with the {}.  But with the brackets {} it is working. It is also working without the brackets. YII2 is an very confusing framework. I don't understand it all. But anyway than k you for your critical  look and found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

These rules appear slightly nonsensical, when comparing them to the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$rules-detail).
It's probably more alike this (`<controller>` is just a wildcard used for standard CRUD):

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => ['user'], 
    'pluralize' => false,
    'patterns' => [
        'POST user/login' => 'user/login',
        'POST user'       => 'user/signup'               
    ]    
]
```

The verb `OPTIONS` should be handled with `.htaccess`. Setting breakpoints inside [`UrlManager.php`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlManager.php) might support the understanding of these rule-sets. In every case, the documentation seems to be incorrect about not supporting verb `OPTIONS`, because [line 236](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlManager.php#L236) reads:

```
$verbs = 'GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS';
```

Also see [The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0 - Routing](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing).

Comment: #Martin Zeitler.And I came across this repository: https://github.com/chrisleekr/yii2-angular-boilerplate/blob/master/api/config/web.php. And it seems that it is working with the extraPatterns option

Comment: #Martin Zeitler.Thank you for your feedback. And at the link you have provided: yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing. it's literally right there 'extraPatterns' => [ 'GET search' => 'search', ], I am now more confused then before. And still don't understand the answare.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton The `extraPatterns` property seems to be for adding additional pattern to existing rules - this may only have effect, when having previously applied `patterns`. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$extraPatterns-detail

Comment: Then I don't understand what I have to change